# Can't we enforce a limited number of attempts to prevent quantum computing from cracking our RSA encryption in the future? Or am I missing something?

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, rsa, quantum-computing

It is often said that quantum computing could eventually be the end of modern encryption, and data security companies will eventually need to discover and implement quantum safe encryption. But can't a company just set limits on how many password attempts are allowed in a given time? Couldn't this slow down the brute force enough to keep data safe for several hundred+ years?

Comment: No, you can't "set limits" to how math works.

Comment: Quantum computers are not magic. See [PQRSA](https://cr.yp.to/talks/2018.04.11-2/slides-djb-20180411-2-pqrsa-16x9.pdf) paper that fooled NIST rules!

Comment: Your question is about password attempt, actually, it is about the key search. See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/242021/86735

Comment: Can you please explain more? Is it because the encrypted message has to be public and the quantum computer can attempt to crack it as many times as it'd like?